# javascript module always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, module, undefined

I'm a noob in Javascript and I try to implement a module but whenever I call a method in this module it returns undefined.

please help!

```
"use strict";
var MODULE = (function() {
  var res = {};
  res.Student = function(name, firstname, id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.id = id;
    this.print = function() {
      console.log("student: " + this.name + ', ' + this.firstname + ', ' + this.id);
    }
  };

  res.ForeignStudent = function(name, firstname, id, nationalite) {
    Student.apply(this, arguments);
    this.nationalite = nationalite;
    this.print = function() {
      console.log("student: " + this.name + ', ' + this.firstname + ', ' + this.id + ', ' + this.nationalite)
    };
  };
  res.ForeignStudent.prototype = new res.Student();
  res.ForeignStudent.prototype.constructor = res.ForeignStudent;
  return res;
}());
var x = MODULE;
x.Student("Dupond", "Jean", 1835).print(); // Cannot read property 'print' of undefined
```

Comment: You're missing a `new`: `new x.Student("Dupond","Jean",1835).print();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include `new` before `x.Student`, that is new `x.Student("Dupond","Jean",1835).print();`

When the code new Foo(...) is executed, the following things happen:

- A new object is created, inheriting from Foo.prototype.
- The constructor function Foo is called with the specified arguments,
  and with this bound to the newly created object. new Foo is
  equivalent to new Foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, Foo
  is called without arguments.
- The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of
  the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't
  explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
  instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can
  choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
  process.)

You can find out more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

```js
"use strict";
var MODULE=(function(){
 var res={};
 res.Student=function (name,firstname,id){
   this.name=name;
   this.firstname=firstname;
   this.id=id;
   this.print=function(){
   console.log("student: "+ this.name+', '+this.firstname+', '+this.id);
  
   }
  };

 res.ForeignStudent=function (name,firstname,id,nationalite){
   Student.apply(this,arguments);
   this.nationalite=nationalite;
   this.print=function(){
   console.log("student: "+ this.name+', '+this.firstname+', '+this.id+', '+this.nationalite)
   };
  };
 res.ForeignStudent.prototype = new res.Student();
 res.ForeignStudent.prototype.constructor = res.ForeignStudent;
 return res;

}());
var x=MODULE;
new x.Student("Dupond","Jean",1835).print();
```

Comment: @Akihiko please accept it as answer, if it helped. Thank you